# Solving a large linear system

Tags: equation-solving

I have a system of 12 equations with very large symbolic expressions but linear in some variables that I want to solve it for. I have been running `Solve` for many hours now to no avail. The `LeafCount` of the system is over 400 millions. Will `Solve` be able to solve it?

Comment: It is unlikely that anybody could answer your question meaningfully without access to the actual system.

Comment: In some cases, you can help Mathematica solve systems of equations that `Solve` will fail to solve by itself.  For example, you might pick a single variable, solve for that and then back-substitute. You might identify common sub-expressions and replace these with some intermediate constant.  You might be able to express your equations in matrix form.  Inverting the matrix symbolically might be impractical, but it could give you insight to the problem.

Comment: This sounds like something that you have to do nimerically. Leaf counts in the millions means that no human being would be able to interpret the outcome.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you **do** with a solution that `Solve` may return?

Comment: @mikado Yes, that's what I have been trying to do. I have found values for some variables. I thought there would be another way to proceed.